# Can MySQL order by a comparison function?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql function which defines an ordering on table rows, given primary keys

```
CREATE FUNCTION CmpRows (a INT, b INT)
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT foo FROM Bar WHERE id=a) etc...)
    THEN
        RETURN -1;
    ELSEIF (other stuff)
    THEN
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
 END
```

Can I make MySQL use this function to ORDER BY a result set?

Comment: Yes, it should work.  Have you tried using this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't know what the syntax would be in the context of `SELECT ... ORDER BY CmpRows(???,???)` -- how do I tell it to use primary keys in place of the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Declare this function to be deterministic

```
 CREATE DETERMINISTIC FUNCTION ...
```

And, don't lie when you declare it. Make sure it really is deterministic. That is, make sure its results are the same every time for the same inputs.

Then it should work.

Comment: Is the function still deterministic if the rows pointed-to by the arguments can change between invocations?

Comment: No, a function is not deterministic if there is any possibility whatsoever that the result will change given the same arguments.  You may want to consider a different approach to ordering your result set; this one, if you can get it to work at all, may yield surprising results when you don't want to be surprised.

Comment: So if it's not deterministic, and I `SELECT...ORDER BY CmpRows` then change some rows, then `SELECT...ORDER BY CmpRows`, then the order the second time around might be the same as the order the first time round, or something like that?